# Positive antonym for trendy in fashion or overall personal appearance?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

How do you describe someone's fashion sense in a positive way when it is the opposite of 'trendy'? By opposite of trendy I mean that it may still be considered to 'look good' (even though this is subjective), but not popular (many may not like it), not contemporary (it may borrow from old fashioned styles) and not generally in style (but unique and individual). A good example of this could be any of the many [alternative fashions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_fashion), however the extra challenge here is if you want to describe not based on labels of pre-existing alterntaive fashions, but just to emphasize that it's not trendy.

This may come down to providing a more detailed description, but I thought I would try to see if there is a more concise way to describe this.

Comment: The word ‘quaint’ comes to mind. It means ‘attractive because of being unusual and especially old-fashioned.’

Comment: I think the word "alternative" (which you used in your question) is a good choice.  You could also use "unique" or "own [e.g. 'She has her *own* sense of style.']."  "Own" would create a tautology, so it emphasizes that the style is *hers,* not anyone else's.

Comment: **Classic, timeless, retro.**

Comment: @John B. this is great please change this to an answer

Comment: @FrontEnd I have written it out as an answer.  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Alternative [or 'alt']," "unique,"** **"own,"** and many synonyms (and related words) of these are all applicable.

"Alternative" (which you used in your question) is defined as:

> Relating to behavior that is considered unconventional and is often seen as a challenge to traditional norms. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alternative)]

"Unique" is defined as:

> Particularly remarkable, special, or unusual. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unique)]

"Own" creates a tautology, which puts an emphasis on that the style is *hers,* not anyone else's.  It is defined as:

> Particular to the person or thing mentioned; individual. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/own)]

*Some potentially applicable synonyms* (and a few that are *related,* but not synonyms) of these words are:

> Unonventional, unorthodox, quirky, quaint, whimsical, zany, etc...